# Hall effect sensors for BLDC CW and CW positioning

Tags: inverter, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

Hi I have just designed a BLDC controller and I have it running in both CW and CCW directions. I have noticed that when operating in CCW the motor is less noisy and more smoother than when operating in CW. I was wondering if the hall sensors need to be repositioned for CW operation or perhaps is there a requirement to use 2 sets of sensors, 1 set for CCW and 1 set for CW to make the operation more smoother?

Comment: Your problem probably mechanical.

Comment: More likely you need to adjust the timing relationships in the controller when switching direction.